# Show list of files changed in recent commits in a specific directory

Tags: git

In Subversion, `svn log` displays commit log messages [(reference)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).

How can I do the following in git?

```
svn log -v -l 10 ./
```

Answer (score 223, accepted):

This one is more similar to the svn command as it shows the file status: Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R), and others.

```
git log --name-status -10 path/to/dir
```

It is worth looking at the full documentation page for [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).  There you will learn that `-10` refers to the past 10 commits, and `-p` will give you the full patch, among a variety of other goodies.

Comment: For completeness: the commonly used set of similar options is `-p` (full patch), `--stat` (numbers of changed lines), `--numstat` (like `--stat` but machine-readable), `--name-status`, and `--name-only` (just the filenames).

Comment: For anyone coming to this question without knowing already, the -10 refers to the number of commits you want shown. If you need a comprehensive list of commits, try making the number unusually large, like -1000 or more as needed.

Comment: Is it also possible to view the history since a specific commit or label? It's hundreds of commits ago, so trying to count that...

Comment: @MrFox `git log <from revision>..`, e.g. `git log abc123..`. Read more about the range format here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_ranges

Answer (score 53):

To show all files changed in the last 10 commits, without any commit information, do:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~10..HEAD yourdir
```

Comment: Perfect solution for reopening files in your editor.

Comment: This solution lists file paths only, *no* comments, which is much appreciated over the accepted answer. **If all you want is a list of the files that have changed in the specified commits, and this solution does just that**.

Comment: A drawback is that it checks the last 10 commits of the entire repo, not just the last 10 of "yourdir"

Answer (score 8):

Try to do

```
git log -p -10 yourdir/
```

It should work.

Comment: The OP asked for a list of files changed, not the full patch.

Comment: If you want the list of file changed, you can do --stat in place of -p

Answer (score 2):

To show all the `commit` of your branch(recent and old), you need to count the number of commits in the branch

```
git rev-list --count branch_name
```

Once you get all the commit count, you can run

```
git log --name-status -countNumber /path
```

Comment: And one can simplify the view adding the `--pretty=oneline` option to the `git log` command above. Appending a `| sort | uniq` command will help one see the A/C/D/M/R status tagging as per [htanata's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106051)

Answer (score 2):

I've had great luck with this:

```
$ git reflog --name-status -10 <path/to/folder/of/interest>
```

Finds things `log` does not.  Pipe output to grep if you know part of a name.

Answer (score 1):

> git show $commitId$ --name-only

It will result in the files which are changed during this commit