# command to find if anything below a given directory was changed in the last commit

Tags: git

To speed up running tests during CI, I need to know for a given directory if anything in or below that directory was changed in the last commit, so I can skip the tests for that directory.

Does such a command exist? I am not looking for the specific files that changed, just for a command that exits 1 if anything was changed, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git -> show list of files changed in recent commits in a specific directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104764/git-show-list-of-files-changed-in-recent-commits-in-a-specific-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention CI, I assume you are writing a script. Then you should use the "plumbing" (low-level) commands. This would do:

```
if git diff-tree --quiet --exit-code HEAD^:"$subdir" HEAD:"$subdir"
then
    # no change
else
    # there was a change
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!