# Can I see a count of files with some extensions through git history?

Tags: git

In the project I and my team working currently, there are `.js` files which are considered outdated in favor of `.ts` files as we are migrating our code to TypeScript.

As the project is large and we cannot convert all files to TypeScript at once, we are doing it gradually.

To see the dynamics, I am thinking of the way to track the number of both `.js` and `.ts` files in the project and then visualizing collected data as a chart.

Is it possible to somehow scan all the history and get count of files with some extension in each commit?

Comment: If you're OK with counting lines rather than files then have a look at [Git Locust](https://github.com/Munkei/git-locust) (disclaimer: I'm the creator of Git Locust).

Comment: @Biffen what do you means by _counting lines_

Comment: @AxelH Counting lines of code, like [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) does (which is arguably a more accurate measurement anyway).

Comment: @Biffen Cloc seems to show the number of file per langage. So this would be enough for the OP.

Comment: @AxelH Yes, but Git Locust only shows lines.

Comment: @AxelH …but Git Locust takes care of both measuring each commit and generating a graph, which cloc can't do.

Comment: @Biffen I agree, your project have interesting part but since it doesn't provide the specific functionnality that could help OP, this would not be enough, if you provide the number of lines AND the names of files, then you could easily add a functionnality to count the number a distinct file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use [Cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc)

> Invoke cloc to count your source files, directories, or archives.

Here is the example from GitHub

```
prompt> cloc gcc-5.2.0/gcc/c
      16 text files.
      15 unique files.
       3 files ignored.

https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.65  T=0.23 s (57.1 files/s, 188914.0 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C                               10           4680           6621          30812
C/C++ Header                     3             99            286            496
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            13           4779           6907          31308
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You could do it on the git directory and see the number of file per language. Of course, you would need to be able to list the files per commit.

This would need a good script using probably the log to see the changes to find the files

```
git log --name-status -10 path/to/dir
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106051/4391450)