# List the latest edited files in git

Tags: git

I have a repository in git where I have several .js codes, I would like to know if there is a command to list the last modified files, take their names and send a script to execute these last modified codes

example:
i have

```
code.js x;
code.js y;
code.js z;
```

code.js x and y was edited today I would like to get in git a command that would return the file name for me to go fetch in the directory and execute those changed codes

Comment: Unclear what "codes" or "wheels" are

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git -> show list of files changed in recent commits in a specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104764/git-show-list-of-files-changed-in-recent-commits-in-a-specific-directory). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18666957/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show files modified in the last commit of a branch

```
git log -n1 --name-only <branch>
```

On any branch

```
git log -n1 --name-only --all
```